# How do I properly reference Content in Visual Studio 2010 with XNA?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, xna, xna-4.0

I'm making a C# game using Visual C# Studio 2010 Express with Microsoft's XNA.

At the moment I'm trying to load content into the game but I'm having trouble with the relative Content path. My current code looks like this:

```
private Texture2D planetBackground;
private Texture2D groundFacility;
private Texture2D hoverShip;
private Texture2D attackShip;

protected override void LoadContent()
{
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
    planetBackground = Content.Load<Texture2D>("spacebackground.png");
    groundFacility = Content.Load<Texture2D>("planetstation.png");
    hoverShip = Content.Load<Texture2D>("ship2.png");
    attackShip = Content.Load<Texture2D>("ship1.png");
}
```

The `Content.RootDirectory` is currently set to "Content".

How do I construct the paths to the images so that they will load? At the moment I get a `ContentLoadException: file not found`, so clearly my relative path is wrong. Where does the path start from?

Comment: Content/path. You should look up more on google. Also post code whenever you try something that does not work.

Comment: ...there is code in the question and has been since I posted it.

Comment: It start from `YourApp/Content`. The reference in the code is correct, so now you should place your pictures in a folder named Content at the root of your project, something like `YourApp/Content/spacebackground.png`. And I highly recommend using MonoGame since XNA have been dead for multiple years now. AFAIK they still use XNA's content pipeline, so the step won't be too high.

Comment: Sorry my phone must have bugged it did not load the code. I believe you need the folder those files are in if they are in separate folders inside content folder.

Comment: Never mind, mixed things up a bit with MonoGame again. In XNA you can directly create a [Content project](http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/managing-content) and load the file without the extension. With MonoGame you need a folder, with XNA you can use the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove file extensions:

```
planetBackground = Content.Load<Texture2D>("spacebackground");
```

XNA transforms all files into .XNB files, so there's no need to specify extensions (unless your files have multiple dots in file names).

Comment: Works a charm. Thanks